# How exactly is the logger a singleton and how are different log files created? Implemented my own logger for understanding

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, log4j, singleton

In order to better understand how debug loggers work, I tried to implement my own logger in java. Shown in the code below. As far as I understand loggers are usually singletons. I want to use the same instance in different classes of my application. Each class where I use this logger will log to a different file. But that would mean that the singleton is being mutated by different objects. Wouldn't this cause inaccurately logging one classes debug output into a file that should be logged into by the other class. Since the same logger instance is shared across the entire app, how do different files get generated? Its the SAME instance being mutated in the application. So I decided to make the logFile location a final but then all classes would log to the same file. Could you shed some light on these curiosities?

Thank you in advance.

```
public class Logger {

    private final String logFile;
    private static Logger instance;

    private Logger(String logFile){
        this.logFile = logFile;
    }

    public Logger getInstance(String logFile){
        synchronized(Logger.class){
            if(instance==null){
                instance = new Logger(logFile);
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void write(String data) throws IOException{
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile)));
        out.write(data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not implement another logger. There are already too much of them. slf4j, log4j, logback, commons-logging, or the logging included in java.

Comment: Again, I'm not implementing another logger. Trying to learn how how the internals may work. Best way to understand is to try and code a little version of it in eclipse.

Comment: Generally speaking, the logger objects *aren't* singletons but rather arranged in a hierarchy. Usually, each class gets its own `private static final` logger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you want understand the logger implementation you can read the source code of log4j. But in log4j loggers are not singleton, there are multiple instances, it uses repository and factory patterns.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based purely on the understanding of the default logging facility in Java (in `java.util.logging`). 
The fundamental difference to note here is that the job of a `Logger` object is to provide a mechanism to *generate* the logs. It is not really responsible for *streaming* the logs anywhere. That is the job of the Handlers (`ConsoleHandler`, `FileHandler`, et cetera), since he generated logs are shipped as `LogRecord` objects, which are exported by the `Handler` to a variety of destinations including memory, output streams, consoles, files, and sockets.

Now, we are using the `Logger` object just to generate the corresponding `LogRecord`. Its job is just to respond to logging calls and that's it. As a singleton, no matter where you use it, its state remains the same since it is not concerned with streaming it to different locations, thereby demanding **no** change in its attributes.

So, reiterating myself, **nothing really changes with respect to the `Logger`**, which is a perfect choice for the use of singletons. It is **the `Handler` that facilitates the logs into different destinations**, depending on whatever classes one is using.

Some clarifications on the [logging architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html) as well as the [process of logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) are linked. I feel the second link clears out a *lot* of confusion with respect to how things work.